# C# declaring an array

Tags: arrays, model-view-controller

Can anyone explain to me the difference between the two arrays?

```
string[] adminUsers = { "user1", "user2","user3" };
                    VS
var adminUsers = new string[] { "user1", "user2","user3" };
```

Which is the better way to declare an array?

Answer (score 2):

They are the same. [MSDN states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#code-snippet-14) "You can also omit the `new` operator"

Comment: As a bonus note, this question and answer is the same for Java, except for `var`.